# Insert data from googlesheets to my website (using PHP)?

Tags: php, google-sheets

Is there any possible way to insert data from my GoogleSheets to PHP?

Let's say I have a sheet called "Sheet1" and "A1" cell.

I want to insert that A1 cell data to my website using Php (dynamically).

So that anytime I update "A1" cell, the data will dynamically update on my website.

Thanks

Comment: Please go read [ask]. This site is meant for _specific_ questions about problems with code you have written, not to do your basic initial research for you.

Comment: there are loads of libraries for doing this on packagist. that should have been your first place to check, not here https://packagist.org/?query=google%20sheets

Answer (score 1):

You can read more information about Google Sheets here
[Google Sheets Api](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php)

First you can see Php example, and on the left side you can see more menu options about create, read or edit spreadsheet.
If you want this data to be updated automatically, you need to search more information about webhooks, and how to attach webhook to google

Comment: thanks! I guess that's exactly what I needed.

Comment: @RaymondM no problem :)